# Apache broken after ubuntu upgrade

Tags: apache2

I have 3 sites: two Joomla and one Squirrel Webmail.

I recently updated Ubuntu from 12.04 to 14 and Apache broke.

**Site 1:** 9.90.132.94

> When i browse to site 1 it says forbidden.

**Site 2:** [www.tczfans.info](http://www.tczfans.info)

> When i  browse to site 2 all i get is a directory listing.

You can see all my configuration files by browsing to http://www.tczfans.info.

Please help!

Comment: This is horrible to read. Please, format your question.

Answer (score 1):

Site 1: This site does not exist or the server does not respond. According to your config your ip address is supposed to be 69.90.132.94, it is not 9.90.132.94 as you've stated in you question. If that's correct then refer to below.
Site 2: This clearly demonstrates that the webserver is working. You should reconfigure the webserver according to the new version. Apache 2.4 has slightly different requirements and settings than Apache 2.2.
Take a look at `http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html` for more info, especially the part about 'access control'.